# React initial useState value from props is not being set

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I have an Avatar component which is being passed a non-null `url`. I'm trying to set the initial value of `avatarPath` to this `url` but `avatarPath` is null.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Avatar({ uid, url, size, onUpload }) {
  const [avatarPath, setAvatarPath] = useState(url);


  console.log(url);
  console.log(avatarPath);
```

In the console, the values logged are:

```
0.jpg
null
```

My current workaround is doing this:

```
export default function Avatar({ uid, url, size, onUpload }) {
  const [avatarPath, setAvatarPath] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setAvatarPath(url);
  }, [url]);
```

Comment: is the parent component re-rendering the Avatar component multiple times? if yes, with what values?

Answer (score 0):

Everytime the Avatar component rerenders `useState(url)` will run. But the way `useState` hook works is that it will only use the `url` value once. And after that any change to the state value will be caused by `setState`. If `useState` will change the value of `avatarPath` after every re-render it will be quite useless because it will resetting the value of `avatarPath` everytime with the initial value.

The [docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#storing-information-from-previous-renders) suggest:

> If the value you need can be computed entirely from the current props or other state, remove that redundant state altogether.

And if that is not the case, then the way you are doing is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In the above code, you are trying to access variable *avatarPath* ryt after you are setting useState and as you know `useState is an asynchronous hook, it will wait for the component to finish its cycle, re-render, and then it will update the state.`

Thus you might need to proceed with another operation after your value for *avatarPath* is set.

e.g.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Avatar({ uid, url, size, onUpload }) {
  const [avatarPath, setAvatarPath] = useState(url);

useEffect (() => {
  console.log(url);
  console.log(avatarPath);

// Your logic goes here

},[avatarPath])
```